# How to enable JAX-RS 1.1 feature in Worklight server

Tags: eclipse, jax-rs, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I am trying a sample project that requires me to enable the JAX-RS 1.1 provided IBM worklight server. However I am not able to find that feature in eclipse server.xml design page. Please suggest how I can get that enabled.

[image: Unable to find Feature jax-rs 1.1 Please help!!]

[image: Screenshot provided in the tutorial]

Comment: Which sample are we talking about? Link?

Comment: Its an internal training doc shared by my org for running jquery mobile on Websphere liberty Profile, I can share you a screenshot probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check in this subdirectory of Eclipse, you will see that the Liberty server included in Worklight Studio does not include the jax-rs 1.1 feature.

/plugins/com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.1.0.00-20131219-1900/liberty/wlp/lib

This is not documented. I figure this out because it also does not include the managed-beans 1.0 feature, which I needed for a project this week.

For reference here is the list of all Liberty profile features: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Fae%2Frwlp_feat.html

You might be able to copy the jax-rs 1.1 feature from a full Liberty install by following these directions (I haven't tested this, and would hesitate to do so inside of Worklight Studio, obviously not a supported modification): http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Fae%2Frwlp_feat.html

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was supposed to be supported.

Liberty Core supports the JEE Web Profile which contains JAX-RS.  See  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc%2Fae%2Frwlp_feat.html

Did you try adding `<feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>` to the server.xml file?

Comment: Also note if you use the JAX-RS feature you probably need to specify the servlet feature as it says on the last line of http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Fae%2Ftwbs_jaxrs_plan.html

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but the server.xml started throwing warnings. So removed it. Also I am using Worklight studio for Eclipse, not the stock WAS 8.5 liberty profile so am guessing that might be reason why its not bundled with it.